# change default anchoring position

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I am developing an MFC dialog based application and when I maximize the dialog, empty space is added to "right and bottom" of controls. This is because controls have default anchoring position set to TOP-LEFT.

I want the empty space to be added to "left and bottom" of controls means all the controls present in dialog need to be at same distance from right and top of dialog. Also, I do not want to expand the size of control.

So, Is there any way to change the default anchoring of controls to TOP-RIGHT?

PS : There are so many controls on dialog and I do not want to change the property of each one. A common method/property for all is required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If fear you need to do it manually, but it's not a big deal: multiselect the items you want to change by Ctrl-clicking them or press Ctrl+A for selecting them all, and then change the anchoring. This will change the anchoring for all selected items.

Comment: Coordinates are relative to the top-left corner. As a workaround, I would consider putting all controls on another dialog, with the child style set. Then capture the maximize, restore, size etc events (for the main/parent dialog) and move the child dialog as needed - this would move all controls at once.